# Proof that $||\vec{E}|| = c||\vec{B}||$ for electromagnetic waves from maxwells equations in vacuum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations

Starting from Maxwell-equations in vacuum :

$$
\nabla \cdot \vec{E} = 0
$$
$$
\nabla \times \vec{E} = - \frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}
$$
$$
\nabla \cdot \vec{B} = 0
$$
$$
\nabla \times \vec{B} = \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}
$$

We can show the existence of electromagnetic waves (using the identity $\nabla \times \nabla \times \vec{F} = \nabla(\nabla \cdot F) - \nabla^2 \vec{F})$ :

$$
\frac{\partial^2 \vec{E}}{\partial t^2} = c^2 \nabla^2 \vec{E}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial^2 \vec{B}}{\partial t^2} = c^2 \nabla^2 \vec{B}
$$

The solutions to these equations are the following for plane waves (using $\mathbb{C}$ notation) :

$$
\vec{E}(\vec{r}, t) = \vec{E_0}e^{i(\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r} - wt)}
$$

$$
\vec{B}(\vec{r}, t) = \vec{B_0}e^{i(\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r} - wt)}
$$

We can show (using divergence of the electric and magnetic field in vacuum) that these waves form an orthonormal basis $(\vec{E}, \vec{B}, \vec{k})$

However, I'm looking for a proof that :

$$
  ||\vec{E}|| = c||\vec{B}||
$$

I've looked everywhere, in Griffith electrodynamics, in my books (Berkeley vol. II and III) but I've found nothing.

Comment: Try substituting those solutions into one of the two Maxwell equations that relate $\vec E$ and $\vec B$.

Comment: Yeah, I had that feeling but then I get for example for the curl of the electric field : $\nabla \times  \vec{E_0}e^{i(\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r} - wt)} = - \omega \vec{B(\vec{r}, t)}$

But I don't know how to calculate this curl ?

Comment: *I don't know how to calculate this curl* Use $\vec k\cdot\vec r=k_xx+k_yy+k_zz$ and take the appropriate partial derivatives.

Answer (score 2):

The short proof is as follows.
Your second Maxwell equation in vacuum states among others that
$$ k||\vec{E}|| = \omega||\vec{B}|| \, .$$
Since $\omega = kc$ it follows that $$||\vec{E}|| = c||\vec{B}||\, .$$

Comment: This only works for plane waves. You always have $\partial_t\vec{B}=-i\omega\vec{B}$, but $\nabla\times\vec{E}=i\vec{k}\times\vec{E}$ won't necessarily hold for arbitrary waves.

Answer (score 1):

The relations between the electric field and the magnetic field for the solutions of Maxwell equations in vacuum are (wave planes):

$$\vec{E}=c \hspace{0.1cm} \vec{k} \times \vec{B}$$
$$\vec{B}=\frac{1}{c} \vec{k} \times \vec{E}$$

$\vec{k} is unitary, I dont know how to write unitary vectors here.Take modules in any equation and u will get ur relation.

Edit: These relations are deduced for sure in the Griffiths book for Electromagnetism.

Comment: *I dont know how to write unitary vectors* Write \hat{k} to get $\hat{k}$. In English this is called a “unit vector”.